# Title inside SVG rect not showing

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs

I have a `React` component in which I am mapping over some elements and for each one I am returning a marker represented by `rect` that has a `title` and is painted in an `svg`. The marker is displayed correctly in the `svg` but the tooltip is not showing when I hover over it.

Here is what my svg looks like
[image]

My `svg` has more or less the following structure:

```
<svg>
    <g>
        {this.renderLines()}
        {this.renderMarkers()}
    </g>
</svg>
```

And each marker is created like this, where `key`, `x`, `y`, `color`, and `name` are some parameters:

```
<rect key={key}
      width='8px'
      height='8px'
      x={x}
      y={y}
      fill={color} >
      <title>{name}</title>
</rect>
```

If I need to provide any more info or code, let me know.

**EDIT**

So, I found where the problem is but don't know how to fix it without breaking the code.

The component has the following structure after all:

```
<svg>
    <g>
        {this.renderLines()}
        {this.renderMarkers()}
    </g>
    <rect />
</svg>
```

where the `rect` is getting a zoom handler attached to it via `d3` library, in order for the chart to have zoom functionality. The problem is that this rect is on the foreground and thus the `onHover` event of the markers isn't fired.

Moving the `rect` zoom pane on top of the `svg` solves the tooltip showing problem, but when the mouse is over a marker, then zoom doesn't work. It has to `mouseOut` of the marker for it to work.

Comment: it's rendering a `rect` for each element I'm mapping over

Comment: Each marker is just a `rect` containing a `title` as I've mentioned in the question

Comment: Just `rect`s inside a `g` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally solved it. Here is what I did:

1. made `rect` the first child of the `svg`
2. attached the zoom functionality to the `rect` markers via the `ref` as a callback